# Swiping Tabs with static footer menu - Android

Tags: android, footer, swipe, swipeview

I've created SwipingTab with two Fragments. Now I want to add menu on bottom to be fixed, static. When user swipe between tabs, that menu should not moving. Where should I create that menu. I tried on main_layout.xml, but cannot. Any suggestion or idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would set up the main view with tabs

[image: See image below]

Then the footermenu would inflate a fragment that will be used as a menu. You can follow this [Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) to add swapeable tabs

Comment: It gives me error: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. I don;t know why, but I cannot adding anything on this layout..

Comment: You should add ViewPager and footermenu in a linearlayout or relativelayout. As you can see from the above image, LinearLayout is the root element